# kivy(v1.8) Clock.unschedule() -> AttributeError: no attribute "is_done"

Tags: python, callback, kivy, clock

Overflow community,

I am struggeling right now with the following problem: 
I want to have various callback-events running (having their own amount of arguments passed additionally, so using something like "partial" comes into play as well) in parallel and I want to have buttons to cancel them individually. I tried this for one event to begin with in various ways. Using lambda notation, global variables or adressing the "Clock._events['']. Also, I enhanced an example that I found on the net which makes use of a new class to even pass further variables to the callback-function. One code-snipped, that produces the same error that I get for all my approaches is the following:

```python
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CallbackHelper:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.app = args[0][0]
        self.instance = args[0][1]
        print 'writing from init'
        print self.app
        print self.instance

    def __call__(self, *args):
        MyWidget.my_callback(self.app, self.instance)
        print Clock._events



Builder.load_string("""
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "Print events"
        on_press: print(Clock._events)
    Button:
        text: "Add event"
        on_press: root.start_callback(self)
    Button:
        text: "Unschedule event"
        on_press: root.start_unschedule(self) 
""")

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    callback_var = []
    def my_callback(self, *args):
        print("my_callback")

    def start_callback(self, instance):
        self.callback_var = Clock.schedule_interval(CallbackHelper([self, instance]), 1)

    def start_unschedule(self,instance):
        Clock.unschedule(self.callback_var)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The error produced is:

```bsh
my_callback
{'default': [<ClockEvent callback=<__main__.CallbackHelper instance at 0x000000000642D248>>], '_purge_by_timeout': [<ClockEvent callback=<function _purge_by_timeout at 0x0000000004B18668>>]}
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "[...]/test/functionScheduleCheck.py", line 53, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 792, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 481, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 381, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_pygame.py", line 287, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 324, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 309, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 220, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4537)
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 645, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4537)
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 657, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4537)
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 284, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "_event.pyx", line 316, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4537)
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors.py", line 93, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "_event.pyx", line 312, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:4491)
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1299, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
   File "[...]/test/functionScheduleCheck.py", line 46, in start_unschedule
     Clock.unschedule(self.callback_var)
   File "[...]\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 505, in unschedule
     if callback.is_done:
 AttributeError: 'ClockEvent' object has no attribute 'is_done'
```

E.g. storing the event as a global variable EVENT and then calling **EVENT.cancel()** does nothing btw.

Any ideas?

I really appreciate your help,
Tanoshimi

Comment: I played further with the callback functions of kivy but it does not seem to work for me yet, hence I cannot provide any new, working code [given that I am additionally limited to Kivy v1.8 right now].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following:

- upgrading to kivy 1.10 in a new virtualenv (from 1.8)
- migrating the code
- fixing: Clock._events['my_event_name'] to Clock.get_events()[my_event_list_nbr]

now works like a charm. One guess is: callback routines just weren't functionally implemented at kivy v1.8 with respect to cancel() and unschedule routines. Thank you kivy time for having this fixes with a newer installment of the environment.